# MapView zoom depending on the coordinates

Tags: xcode, mkmapview, zooming, coordinates, ios5.1

I am developing an App in IOS 5 with different maps. I wanted to zoom each map depending the coordinates that I get from the server. Each map will have different zoom, as I said. I wanted all the coordinates to appear on the map.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got the best solution for this. First, I must get the max and min values (latitude and longitude) from the server. Finally, I do the following:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D min = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([lati_min floatValue], [longi_min floatValue]);

CLLocationCoordinate2D max = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([lati_max floatValue], [longi_max floatValue]);

CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((max.latitude + min.latitude) / 2.0, (max.longitude + min.longitude) / 2.0);
        MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(max.latitude - min.latitude, max.longitude - min.longitude);
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span);
```

It works perfectly.